# Phpmyadmin keeps throwing me error 1146 'table xxx.xxx doesn't exist' no matter what I do

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, innodb

everything was going well, I have a wordpress database that I was using for my work, but when I uploaded everything my computer crashed, and it looks like the database didn't like it that much. Every single database I had still has it's tables and their .frm and .idb files, but they are empty and Phpmyadmin throws 1146 errors when I try to open them.

I tried reinstalling Mamp, doing it again deleting every single file other than my databases, creating new similar tables and importing my .frm files, using tool such as mysqlcheck... None of these worked.
If you have any idea what could be the solution to this, you'd be my savior and I'd set up an altar in your glory.

I thought it was about my database files, but old backup files won't work either, and they haven't had any modification in a long time. But I looks like it's not only a question of Mamp configuration, because theses files also won't work on my AlwaysData server.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Hi, i'm using InnoDB.

Comment: How did you "upload"?

Comment: I was working on localhost, and I uploaded the website files to Filezilla. I also exported the db and imported in on my host, but I had no metadata, and when I got back to localhost to try exporting again, every table was empty and PMA kept saying they doesn't exist

Comment: How did you "export" and "import".  These are vague terms that are applied in many different situations; we need to know the exact context.

Comment: Ok sorry, so I went on the "export" tab on phpMyAdmin, selected "custom" export method and changed nothing except I checked "export metadata". Then on my second db, I went on the "import" tab and clicked "choose a file", and I clicked ok until it was done. My version of PMA is 4.8.3 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> nothing except I checked "export metadata"

So you dumped only the table definition?  Look in the file that was generated.  Do you see a `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` but no `INSERT ...` statements?

That would explain why the import left you with no data.  But I don't know about the error message.

Comment: Well, this is a way to get something out of his context ahah. No I "CHANGED nothing except...", which means all the other options were set to default. Of course my data were supposed to be here, all the fields required to do this are checked by default in the custom export form.

Comment: @Tchong - And what do you see in the dump file?